# A few questions about ARC for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm fairly new to ARC for iOS (and pretty new to iOS in general) and I have a few quick questions about ARC.

~ In a View Controller, if I do not have statements in my viewDidUnload() method setting my properties to nil, will the properties' memory still be freed when my view controller is released? If so, why do I need to explicitly have this viewDidUnload method?

~ In objects that are not View Controllers, where should I set the properties to nil at? In dealloc? What about primitive properties such as `@property BOOL isActive;`...do I need to set them equal to nil/zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidUnload you need to set outlet references to nil, because ARC will release them and you do not want to accidentally use them after that happens.

You don't have to do anything with properties, they will be handled automatically.  In fact you really do not normally even have a dealloc method any more with ARC.

Comment: One more question that I forgot to ask, suppose I finish using one of my properties midway through execution of view controller code (meaning before viewDidUnload is called), should I set the pointer immediately to nil, or should I just wait for it to eventually be released in viewDidUnload?

Comment: If you're sure you don't need it, I'd nil it right away. Note that despite the name, `viewDidUnload` is **not** a counterpart of `viewDidLoad`; you will sometimes (usually, actually) get `viewDidLoad` called without getting a `viewDidUnload` later.

Comment: Ok, that last sentence confuses me.  What do you mean viewDidUnload is not a counterpart of viewDidLoad? I always assumed that it got called after the ViewController was done being used.

Comment: No. `viewDidUnload` is only called when there's memory stress. It gets skipped in the normal path. `viewDidUnload` is now not only redundant with weak references ARC, but causes a lot of confusion when people assume that it's always called. You should put your cleanup in `viewDidDisappear` or `dealloc`, depending on how early you want it done.

Comment: viewDidUnload is called when a low-memory condition occurs and your view is given the heave-ho.  It's a special situation not likely to occur.

Comment: While viewDidUnload is as noted not a counterpart to viewDidLoad, I don't think it's right to say it's "not likely" to occur.  In fact it is VERY likely to occur.   After your app is run and backgrounded, eventually other apps will want enough memory for iOS to trigger the memory collection routines before it kills your app.  It's only the case it is rare when you are actually running the app (though even there doing anything with images or large data sets can trigger it).

Comment: WWDC 2012 session #200 is very relevant to this discussion, but (as of June 2012) under NDA. I suggest watching it before following this advice.

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need to set your properties to nil as long as they're weak references. IBOutlets should generally be weak references, since they the view controller contains a strong reference to the view, which in turn contains strong references to all of its subviews. (If you have IBOutlets that aren't part of that view hierarchy, they should be strong.)
2. You shouldn't need nil or zero anything, objects or scalars. Xcode will insert nilling statements when working with Interface Builder, but this is it still generating code for pre-ARC Objective-C.

You probably don't even need a `viewDidUnload`; it's only called in special circumstances, when there's low memory stress. Thus, you can't depend on it for cleaning up. Your IBOutlets should be weak, so they'll be cleaned automatically when the view is purged from the viewcontroller (and they'll be restored if the view is reloaded).

I'm assuming here that you're writing a new product, which means you're targeting iOS 5 or later only. If you're targeting iOS 4 in a new product, you really [shouldn't](http://tewha.net/2012/06/dont-write-new-apps-that-target-ios-4/) be. The world has moved on, with 80% of the market on iOS 5 or later. And that's today. Going forward, it's going to be even harder to avoid iOS 5 features for an even smaller percentage of people.

Comment: Note that weak references are only usable in iOS5 forward, many may still be targeting iOS 4.x for a bit longer yet.

Comment: I would note though that for new development now I'd strongly consider iOS5 support only, partly because of the ability to use weak references...

Comment: Yes, for sure! Weak references are the magic bit that turns ARC from "a faster way to produce a product" to "a faster way to produce better product."

Answer (score 1):

Memory management for @properties is handled automatically under ARC.  For times when you have set yourself as delegate, it is common to set the delegate to nil before going away (in viewWillDisapear for instance) so that future calls to delegate don't reference garbage.  Stay tuned for the soon-to-be-posted WWDC videos for the latest guidance.

Comment: Wouldn't we just make the delegate property weak so that we don't have to worry about this?